# "Think Python" exercise to extract URL

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is a exercise in the section 4.21 of the book "How to Think Like a Computer Scientist: Learning with Python 3" 3rd edition

> Suppose any line of text can contain at most one url that starts with “http://” and ends at the next space in the line. Write a fragment of code to extract and print the full url if it is present. (Hint: read the documentation for find. It takes some extra arguments, so you can set a starting point from which it will search.)

Here is the code i wrote and it works.. but i don't think it is really using the "extra arguments" that the author has asked to use. Looking at the find documentation in [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find) i am unable to understand how to use it. Can someone help me with the correct code for this exercise?

```
def findurl(url):
    op_findex = url.find("//")
    op_lindex = url.rfind(" ")
    return url[op_findex+2:op_lindex]

print(findurl("http://example.com/site "))
```

Answer (score 1):

The bug is that you find the last space in the string, not the first space after the beginning of the URL.

```
test = "Hello, visit http://google.com or http://stackoverflow.com for great fun"
start = test.find("http://")
end = test.find(" ", start)
print(test[start:end])
```

You will also notice that `http:` is a necessary and useful part of the extracted URL.